# Hide CDT Time Zone

Tags: calendar, time

I often glance down at my calendar and occasionally look at the CDT time zone instead of my personal time zone.

Is there a way to hide CDT time zone in calendar?  I am running iOS 10 on an iPhone 5.

Alternatively making the calendar bold may work.

I believe this is the same issue here https://blog.appriver.com/2014/12/ios-8-calendar-events-display-dual-time-zones/

Comment: What's CDT & how does it relate to where you actually are?

Comment: @Tetsujin Central Time Zone.  It is an hour off from mine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no wiser... central *where*, & how does it relate geographically to where you actually are? Are you near a time zone border?

Comment: @Tetsujin https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone  I am https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone I am not near any borders.  There is an hour difference.  I would need to blur out my email address which I can't do on my phone easily right now to post a picture.

Comment: a) you cannot assume everybody lives in america. b) if you are not near any border how come your 'local time' is not the same as the time zone you live in?

Comment: @Tetsujin having never lived anywhere but America I assumed and when googling "CDT" central was unique term to North America.  The local time zone is the same.  The issue is calendar displays both times for events.  What I find peculiar about this is why it is choosing to display central in addition to eastern when eastern is more commonly used in business because of New York being there.

Comment: @Tetsujin so I determined this is a google and Apple not working together well issue.  I have posted an answer as I am not sure who is at fault for this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am using Gmail for my calendar.

Apparently despite not having "use 2nd time zone" checked in Gmail it still displays the second time zone on Apple devices for some bizarre reason.

If you go to calendar.google.com and settings and change you second time zone to match your main one it will no longer display.

I am not sure if this a a google or Apple bug.